# Выделять ли запятыми словечко "прям"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Меня, прям, до белого каления доводит такое отсутствие элементарного уважения.

Вот в этом предложении "прям" обособляется или всё-таки нет? "Прям" это же, скажем так, разговорная версия "прямо", а случаев обособления этого слова я не знаю, но интонационно так и хочется выделить запятой. Хотя осознаю, что интонация не панацея.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сугубо разговорная конструкция, на грани просторечия, в таких случаях не всегда можно дать однозначную трактовку пунктуации.
Если полагать "прям" правильной частицей, то обособление не требуется, хотя возможно интонационное. А вот если это междометие (или частица в роли междометия) то придется обособлять. 
Если у автора прям усиливает сказанное, то скорее частица. А если паразитное словечко (есть сейчас такая мода, вставлять незначимые слова "типа", "конкретно" и проч.) то скорее всего - междометие. Это автор должен решить, какой у него смысл в этом "прям". 
На первый взгляд больше напоминает именно частицу и именно усилительную, обособления не требующую. Но наверняка - не уверен, ибо у автора могут быть свои резоны. Так что я однозначную рекомендацию "не обособлять" давать бы поостерегся.

Answer (score 2):

Прям (как и прямо) - это разговорная частица со значениями: 1. Совершенно, действительно. 2. Как раз, именно, точно.

В Нацкорпусе приведено 800 примеров, никто не обособляет.

Хотя вот нашелся пример: ― Ну, прям, я заходила несколько раз, а ты то на работе, то по гостям разъезжаешь, ― оправдалась Ника.

Здесь похоже на междометие. Вообще говоря, чтобы "прям" было междометием и обособлялось, нужно чтобы оно не могло относиться к последующему слову, не составляло с ним сочетания.

Comment: — Ну прям, я заходила несколько раз, а ты то на работе, то по гостям ходишь, — оправдалась Ника. В этом примере, видимо, прям относится к ''ну'' поэтому обособляется.

Comment: У этого междометия  по сравнению с частицей семантика особенная: что-то вроде "рассказывай, так я тебе и поверила". Здесь можно использовать "междометное сочетание "ну прям" или  сочетание с обособлением "ага, прям".

Comment: Междометие? Я бы не назвал это слово междометием.

Comment: А как бы назвали?  В любом случае  (междометие, вводное слово) это модальное слово, которое выражает сомнение и которое обособляется.

Comment: В словарях - это частица, усилительное слово, но не междометие.

Comment: Значит, надо поправить словари. Дело не в названии:  частица примыкает к конкретному слову в предложении, а вводные слова и междометия в состав предложения не входят или составляют второй план речи.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае это частица, запятая не нужна.